# How do I disable Visual Studio Code's C++ access modifier indent?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Version 1.15.0 of vscode seems to aggressively change the indenting of access modifiers in C++ code, despite disabling autoIndent and formatOnType.

When I enter this:

```
class Foo
{
    public:
    Foo();
};
```

It gets reformatted as soon as I hit enter after typing "public:", to this:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo();
};
```

In my user settings I have "editor.autoIndent" and "editor.formatOnType" set to false. I also have "C_Cpp.formatting" in the C++ extension set to "Disabled".

Is there some way to control this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set this option to false?

```
"C_Cpp.clang_format_formatOnSave": false,
```

Edited

Also take a look at this option:

```
editor.formatOnSave
```

Comment: I have that set to false. It doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: All of these are false:
"editor.formatOnType": false,
"editor.formatOnPaste": false,
"editor.formatOnSave": false,
"editor.autoIndent": false

Comment: I'm using vscode v1.15.0 too, but  not  run into this problem. Maybe you should check your user configuration again or try to reinstall the c/c++ extension.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this by modifying the language configuration file for C++. It is located in the Microsoft VS Code directory here: resources/app/extension/cpp/language-configuration.json.

I removed the items in the "increaseIndentPattern" and "decreaseIndentPattern" that were related to access modifiers.

This works, but editing the file directly seems like a bad idea.